# Estadisticas de futbol en c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, tablas, codeblocks, tabla-dinámica

Como hago estadística de futbol para registrar marcadores y hacer cálculos de tabla de posición en c++, almacenar en un arreglo unidimensional, la información de la tabla de posiciones.

Se almacena la siguiente información de cada equipo y ordenar según total puntos:

> Nombre del equipo (cadena de caracteres).
>
> Partidos jugados (entero).
>
> Partidos ganados (entero).
>
> Partidos empatados (entero).
>
> Partidos perdidos (entero).
>
> Goles a favor (entero).
>
> Goles en contra (entero).
>
> Diferencia de goles (entero).
>
> Puntos (entero).

Este es mi código pero está mal

```
void tablasposiciones(){ //aglunos códigos tienen errores de coordenandas de tabla de posición y está desordenadas, está mal cálculos de posiciones
    cout << "Selecci\xA2n" << setw(6) << "PJ" << setw(4) << "PG" << setw(4) << "PE" << setw(4) << "PP" << setw(4) << "GF" << setw(4) << "GC" << setw(5) << "Dif" << setw(5) << "Pts" << endl;
    Equipo equipos[] = {
        {equipo1, matriz[0]},
        {equipo2, matriz[1]},
        {equipo3, matriz[2]},
        {equipo4, matriz[3]}
        };
int pos = 1;
for(Equipo const& equipo : equipos)
{
    std::cout << pos << '.' << equipo.nombre << ' ';
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << "|"<<equipo.datos[j]<<"|";
        if(equipo.datos[j] >= 0){
            cout <<" ";
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
}
```

gracias por su compresión

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que está mal? ¿Cómo difiere del comportamiento esperado?

Comment: es que yo tengo que registrar los marcadores pero en tabla sale mal porque está mal los calculos y por eso quería arreglar tabla de clasificación de fútbol...